# React-navigation how to navigate to a route within redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-navigation

I am new to react native with redux. I'm using react native + redux (with redux-thunk) + react-navigation.

I perform an operation within my redux action and intend to call a react-navigation route.

```
export const storeClient = (client) => {

  return async dispatch => {
    ....

    //does not work within action redux
    //this.props.navigation.navigate('ListCliente');  

  }
}
```

There is information there in the react-navigation documentation:

**Warning: in the next major version of React Navigation, to be released in Fall 2018, we will no longer provide any information about how to integrate with Redux and it may cease to work.**

does not react-navigation offer a way to solve this problem? Can someone tell me this? How can I direct the route within the action using the react-navigation

**EDIT**

Is it a good practice to pass navigation as a parameter to use within redux?

*my component*

```
this.props.storeCliente(this.props.navigation, client)
```

my action (redux)

```
export const storeClient = (navigation, client) => {

  return async dispatch => {
    ....

    navigation.navigate('ListCliente');  

  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

** UPDATED

You need to :

1- import NavigationActions into your actions file (i.e. actions.js)

```
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
```

2- Replace every "navigation" with NavigationActions, and your piece of code that calls the navigation, should looks like:

```
const loginUserSuccess = (dispatch, user, navigation) => {

    dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS,
        payload: user,

    });

   NavigationActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'employeeList' })],
    }),


};
```

Comment: Your code is a little far from Redux standards for Actions coding style, anyway, i posted a working function, that navigates to another route after successful login, maybe you can do the same (modify according to your code)